# I created an algorithm that return the square root. Why it is not working?

Tags: c, square-root

> **My code is to working. I made an algorithm that takes a number, discover the base and the roof of the square root of this number( for exemplo, if I want to discover the square root of 5 then tha base will be 2 and the roof will be 5. That means the square root of 5 is between this numbers. But my code goes to a loop when I enter numbers like 5 or 5. Why?**

```
    int raiz_inteira(int valor)
    {
    int impar = 1, cont = 0;
    while(valor >= impar)
    {
       valor = valor - impar;
       cont ++;
       impar+=2;
    }
    return cont;
    }


float raiz_exata(float valor, int base, int teto)
{
    float media = (base+teto)/2.0;
    float erro = media*media-valor;
    printf("%f\n",media);
    if(erro < 0)
    {
        erro *=-1;
    }
    else if(erro == 0)
    {
        return media;
    }
   
    while(erro >0.1)
    {
        printf("%f",media);
        if(media*media >valor)
        {
            teto = media;
        }
        else
        {
            base = media;
        }
        media = (base+teto)/2.0;
        erro = media*media-valor;
        if(erro < 0)
        {
            erro *=-1;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    int teto, base, raiz;
    printf("Type a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&raiz);
    base = raiz_inteira(raiz);
    teto = base+1;
    raiz_exata(raiz,base,teto);
}
```

Comment: Follow through the logic. What happens in your program when you input 5?

Comment: It would make things easier if you translated the code to English. I have no idea what raiz_exata, teto or media should mean.

Comment: *"when I enter numbers like 5 or 5"* - What's the difference between 5 and 5?

Comment: @klutt LIkely _teto_ is the head or upper bound, _base_ is the minimum bound and _media_ is the mean or average.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, cleaned up for easier reading:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int raiz_inteira(int valor) {
    int impar = 1, cont = 0;

    while (valor >= impar) {
        valor -= impar;
        cont++;
        impar += 2;
    }

    return cont;
}

float raiz_exata(float valor, int base, int teto) {
    float media = (base + teto) / 2.0;
    float erro = media * media - valor;

    printf("%f\n", media);

    if (erro < 0) {
        erro *= -1;
    }
    else if (erro == 0) {
        return media;
    }

    while (erro > 0.1) {
        printf("%f", media);

        if (media * media > valor) {
            teto = media;
        }
        else {
            base = media;
        }

        media = (base + teto) / 2.0;
        erro = media * media - valor;

        if (erro < 0) {
            erro *= -1;
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    int teto, base, raiz;
    printf("Type a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &raiz);
    base = raiz_inteira(raiz);

    // printf("base: %d\n", base);

    teto = base + 1;

    // printf("teto: %d\n", teto);

    raiz_exata(raiz, base, teto);
}
```

Now, let's run this, entering 5.

When we start out, `raiz` is 5, `base` is `raiz_inteira(5)` which evaluates to `2`, and `teto` is `3`.

So we enter `raize_exata` with `raiz_exata(5.0, 2, 3)`.

Inside this function, `media` is `2.5`, `erro` is `2.5 * 2.5 - 5.0` which equals `1.25`. *Keep in mind that floats are not always exact values.*

The `2.5` value gets printed.

`1.25` is neither less than `0`, or equal to `0`, so the conditionals are skipped.

Entering the while loop, we again print `2.5`. Because `2.5 * 2.5` is greater than `5.0` `teto` is set to `2`, because `teto` is an `int`.

We then update `media` to be `base + teto / 2.0` which is again `2.5`, so that *has not changed*. Because there's no change there, `error` is not changed. Because it is not less than `0`, the conditional is skipped.

The next go around on the while loop, nothing has changed, so it loops forever.

I'm afraid the language barrier makes it difficult to provide details on how to make this work, but at least we can see why an input of `5` is giving you an infinite loop.

This output seems to happen for any number greater than `2`. You may want to investigate how the transitions from ints to floats are affecting your math.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I was using int instead of float. When I changed this it workd. Teto and base are the roof and floor of my square root. I am from Brazil, so some parts of my code were in portuguese and I forgot to change. Thanks.